# How to give an item to a Guild Member in Dragon Age Legends?

Tags: dragon-age-legends

I'm playing Dragon Age Legends on Google Plus. When I select a piece of loot, I get gifts popping up at the bottom, telling me I can give them to my Guild Members.

[image]

But when I drag it to one of them, nothing happens. **So I'm wondering how I can give an item to a Guild Member?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either a server error, or you're trying to give the gift to an NPC. What's supposed to happen is that you drag the item down to a guild member, and a dialog box will pop up, asking you if you want to pay "shipping costs" to send the selected item to the recipient.

[image]

The cost varies with the value of the item. If you click Send & Post, the item becomes available to the recipient, and the gold and item are deducted from your inventory.

Comment: Ah I reckon it has to be a real player not an NPC?

Comment: Correct. So that could also have been your problem: dragging the item to an NPC just bounces it back to your inventory. (Poor UI design ...) I updated my answer to cover that case.